# Angular 2 Http-Post is not working

Tags: angular

i am trying to send post request to node.js from angular 2. For some reason, after i submit the form, i see the result in url bar of the browser just like i am sending a get request. Additionally, it is reloading the page. I don't get any console errors both from angular and node. I checked it with postman and server is working fine.

url looks like this after the request sent;

http://localhost:3000/?username=testUser&email=test%test.com&password=34242

```
 //server.js
    app.post('/register', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello');
    console.log('success')
    })

//http.service
sendMyData(users : any) {
    let bodyString = JSON.stringify(users); // Stringify payload
    let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
    let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/register', bodyString, options) 
    .map((res : Response) => res.json())
}

//header.component
onSubmit(form : NgForm) {
    this.httpService.sendMyData(form)
      .subscribe(
        (data) => alert(data)
      )
}

//header.component.html
<form (ngSubmit)='onSubmit(f)'  #f='ngForm'>
.......
</form>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but setting the content type to JSON and stringifying the object/array is done by default by Angular. Your code could be reduced to `return this.http.post(url, users).map(...);`.

Comment: Is your URL missing 'register'?

Comment: Since i am sending it as a post request, i don't think url needs to change at all. I just need to get respond and console.log in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved this problem using `this.httpService.sendMyData(form.value)` I totally forgot that "form" returns the whole object with all kind of properties. So it has to be form.value